# How to copy a specific folder in Mobile(Android) using batch?

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

I am new to this ADB and Android SDK. I am following this tutorial : https://www.droidviews.com/push-pull-files-android-using-adb-commands/. And I downloaded fastboot files from https://www.mediafire.com/file/6b3aw3dq8omefyw/mfastboot-v2.zip. And tested and did the basic operations as well. I tested to copy (pull) a folder from mobile to PC with this order of command:

```
adb devices
adb pull /sdcard/Video E:/copied
```

By using above code, I can able to copy all files in Video folder to my destination. But I want to do this by one command in a batch(.bat) file.
How can I do this batch file.

[image: Sample screenshot]

Comment: _"But I want to do this by one command in a batch(.bat) file"_ What do you mean by one command?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, I mean do all this works in one file and one click.

Comment: then copy all your commands line by line into a batch file and try to run it then.

Comment: You seem to have been launching the program in the command prompt...follow @GerhardBarnard's answer. Copy that code into notepad and save it as something.bat and double click it.